# The upper half of a button on my website is not working

Tags: html, css, button

This is my first question on stack overflow so sorry if I'm doing anything wrong.

The lower half of the button is only working and the top part isn't.
How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Here's my code:

```css
   .music{
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      right: 93%;
    }
```

```html
  


    <div class="music">
        <audio id="sound1" src="static/assets/sound/dreams.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        <button style="box-shadow: none; border: none;height:100px;width:120px; background: url(static/assets/img/button.png)" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();"></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working completely fine.

There may be some other things overlapping it.

```css
button {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  color: white;
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/eHH_5rn3xnU/);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="music">
  <audio id="sound1" src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();">play</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').pause();">pause</button>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/wvzVXwg?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Is it being cut off or is it not clickable?

Also, try to avoid inline styles.

For example:

Change:

```
<button style="box-shadow: none; border: none;height:100px;width:120px; background: url(static/assets/img/button.png)" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();">
```

To:

```
button {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();"></button>
```

Comment: It is not clickable

Comment: When you click the upper half of the button does the sound play?

Comment: No, only when i click the lower half it works